# How to read a map in sessionScope from CSJS in Xpages?

Tags: javascript, xpages

Via CSJS would like to read the value in a sessionScope. The sessionScope contains a Hashmap. For example I would like to read the array value that I have stored under key "values".

In Xpages I can call SSJS in a scriptBlock element e.g.:

```
var keyword_custType = '#{javascript: sessionScope.get("customerType")}';
```

But that reads the complete sessionScope variable as a string e.g.:

```
keyword_custType = {default=, values=[Private customer|PRIVATE, Corporate customer|COMPANY, Sole trader|SOLETRADER, Corporate Group|CORPGROUP]}
```

So here I am only interested in the value under key 'values'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried prototyping?

var keyword_custType = '#{javascript: sessionScope.get("customerType").get('values')}';

It should work.